# Git hooks in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ide, githooks, intellij-plugin

I made a git post-merge hook. While testing it, I noticed that IntelliJ does not have native support for them. By the way, I tested the hook from the terminal, and I want to make sure they are supported by teammates' environments.

Is there something I am missing or IntelliJ just does not support client git hooks?

I tried to invoke the merge hook script by merging branches from IntelliJ, but I have not received any feedback from hook. Whereas I got the desired feedback by merging from the terminal.

According to what I have researched, I expect there is no option for receiving git hook feedback in IntelliJ.

Comment: What does the hook do, what did you expect, what did you do.

Comment: If the hook runs when you merge via terminal, it should work via IDE. 

The only thing that I could think of is some ENV variable issues where variables are not passed to intelij. 

1) If the post-merge hook works after you merge via terminal, can you initiate the same command in intelij terminal and check?

If it works in one and not in the other, start IDEA via terminal and test.

Comment: If you activate git hooks they should get executed regardless what client you use to execute git commands.
You can see any hook output in the IntelliJ Git view (CMD-9) console tab.

The only thing that does not properly work is the passing of user input from IntelliJ to a hook.

So if your hook requires user input it will not work in IntelliJ.